# Simple upload file form not working with some browsers

Tags: php, html, forms, upload

I have a problem with upload file forms. I'll write here a simple example of code which is not working in all the browser.

HTML part is something like this:

```
 <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="match.php">
       <input class="btn btn-info" name="dataset" type="file" id="dataset" />
       <input class="btn btn-info" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
 </form>
```

Then, then in match.php file I get and process the file, for example like this:

```
if ($_FILES["dataset"]["error"] > 0 || !($_FILES["dataset"]["size"] > 0)) {
    $dataset = "default.txt";
    echo 'error:' . $_FILES["dataset"]["error"] . ' -  filesize:' . $_FILES["dataset"]["size"];
} else {
    $dataset = $_FILES["dataset"]["tmp_name"];
    echo "Ok";
    print_r($_FILES);
}
```

Very easy: if there are errors during the upload process I will use a default file (and print some error information), otherwise everything's ok.

Well, this works perfectly except in some browsers. For example I encountered the problem with **Android default browser** (not with Chrome), and it seems with some browsers in Windows systems too (I didn't tried it by myself, to be sincere).

Using error information I print, it looks like there's no error in `$_FILES["dataset"]["error"]` (output is 0), but the filesize is **0** (just on these browsers).

There's no problem with folders permissions (I write files in folders using "default.txt" file information), there's no problem with **php.ini** settings (actually I tested it with the same txt file which is 65kb).

Comment: I think some mobile browsers don't support file uploads at all. That could be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the `name` attribute of button. I saw some time ago about this problem.

```
<input class="btn btn-info" type="submit" name="send" value="Submit" />
```